# How write this code in HAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml, erb

How write this ERB code in HAML:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title><%= title %></title>
  <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
  <%== meta_data_tags %>
  <%= favicon_link_tag image_path('favicon.ico') %>
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-touch-icon.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="apple-touch-icon-72x72.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="apple-touch-icon-114x114.png">
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'store/all', :media => 'screen' %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'store/all' %>
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.6/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
  <%= render "spree/shared/routes" %>
  <%= yield :head %>
</head>
```

particularly interested in this

```
<%== meta_data_tags %>
```

code snippet.

Comment: Have you tried [HTML2Haml](http://html2haml.heroku.com/)?  Also, `<%== meta_data_tags %>` looks like a typo.

Comment: I try. But it's no typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found answer for my question:

```
= raw(meta_data_tags)
```

`<%== %>` is the same as `<%= raw() %>`. It's just a fast helper to achieve same result.

Thank you all for help. =)

Answer (score 1):

In Erubis (whch Rails uses) the `<%== ... %>` syntax [escapes the result of the expression](http://www.kuwata-lab.com/erubis/users-guide.02.html#tut-escape). Haml has a [similar feature using `&=`](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#escaping_html).

So a Haml version of `<%== meta_data_tags %>` might look something like:

```
&= meta_data_tags
```

Comment: Yes, it is an option. But it will display html as a string. I answered my question below. Thank you!